# Python MemoryError trying to hash string

Tags: python, out-of-memory

I am developing a program for hashing input string in python, and I can not run it. I am getting MemoryError at the when I try to add together two parts of the string.

```py
File "C:/Users/jacke/PycharmProjects/Hashbrown/Hashbrown.py", line 43, in <module>
    print(hashout(input("Hash input: ")))
  File "C:/Users/jacke/PycharmProjects/Hashbrown/Hashbrown.py", line 8, in hashout
    out = out + hash(x,0)
  File "C:/Users/jacke/PycharmProjects/Hashbrown/Hashbrown.py", line 38, in hash
    jumbled = second_half+first_half
MemoryError
```

Here is my code, I am trying to encode the input string by various transformations and output the hashed string:

```py
import math
import binstr

def hashout(input):
    inputmod = input.replace(" ","spc").replace("y","55ut")
    listofchars=[char for char in inputmod]
    out =""

    for x in listofchars:
        out = out + hash(x,0)
    return(out)

def hash(input,len_out):
    inputlength = 1
    n1 = int(input,32)
    n2 = round(n1*inputlength)**math.sqrt(((inputlength*n1)**math.pi)*1537437/10000000000000000000000)

    n3 = n2-inputlength
    n4 = n3+inputlength + n1

    s1 =str(n4)
    s2 =s1[::-1]
    s3 = s2.replace("e","")
    s3 = s3.replace("+","").replace(".","")

    l1=list(s3)
    n5 = int(l1[0])
    n6 = n5*int(s3)/10000
    n7=(round(n6))

    s99999=str(n7)
    n=2
    line=s99999
    fakeascii=[line[i:i + n] for i in range(0, len(line), n)]

    res = ""
    for val in fakeascii:
        res = res + chr(int(val))
    asciiout=str(res)

    test_str = asciiout.replace(" ","sp")
    bindat=''.join(format(ord(i), 'b') for i in test_str)

    s=(str(bindat*100000000))[::-1]
    first_half = s[0:len(s) // 2]
    second_half = s[len(s) // 2 if len(s) % 2 == 0 else ((len(s) // 2) + 1):]

    jumbled = second_half+first_half
    #out=binstr.bintostr(jumbled)
    out=jumbled
    return(out)

while True :
    print(hashout(input("Hash input: ")))
```

And here is the binstr library:

```py
def BinaryToDecimal(binary):
    binary1 = binary
    decimal, i, n = 0, 0, 0
    while (binary != 0):
        dec = binary % 10
        decimal = decimal + dec * pow(2, i)
        binary = binary // 10
        i += 1
    return (decimal)


def bintostr(bin_data):
    str_data = ' '
    for i in range(0, len(bin_data), 7):
        temp_data = int(bin_data[i:i + 7])
        decimal_data = BinaryToDecimal(temp_data)
        str_data = str_data + chr(decimal_data)
    return(str_data)
```

Answer (score 0):

The code is very badly written but the main problem is here:

```
bindat=''.join(format(ord(i), 'b') for i in test_str)
s=(str(bindat*100000000))[::-1]
```

You set bindat as a string, but then you are trying to multiply is as an integer, the easy override is:

```
bindat=''.join(format(ord(i), 'b') for i in test_str)
s=(str(int(bindat)*100000000))[::-1]
```

Along this, you are not using your binstr library anywhere, there is a commented line but not used at all. The code itself is very suboptimal, you often split something that can be done in one line to multiple lines, for example:

```
n1 = int(input,32)
n2 = round(n1*inputlength)**math.sqrt(((inputlength*n1)**math.pi)*1537437/10000000000000000000000)
n3 = n2-inputlength #why do this at all?
n4 = n3+inputlength + n1 #when you negate it here?
```

can be simplified as:

```
n1 = int(input,32)
n2 = round(n1*inputlength)**math.sqrt(((inputlength*n1)**math.pi)*1537437/10000000000000000000000) + n1
```

Maybe you could add the numbers as variable as well for clarity of the code.

You as well often do steps as assigning a variable but without a reason or use, like `binary1=binary` in `bintostr` without further use of variable `binary1` or `out = jumbled` and then just returning this variable. You should avoid such code for easier readability and better performance. For this reason I recommend you to check out [this guide](https://docs.python-guide.org/writing/style/). It might help you a little with writing nicer code :)